# How to Keep Users Always Logged In

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to keep the user logged in even if the user closes the app. The problem is that if I close the app, I appear in the WelcomePage() instead of the HomePage().

In the main.dart, the initialRoute is the WelcomePage(), but I need it to change once the user has registered or logged in. What do I need to change?

Here's what I have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'pages/account/WelcomePage.dart';
import 'pages/match/HomePage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

// Test
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  //
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //
      initialRoute: WelcomePage.id,
      //
      routes: {
        WelcomePage.id: (context) => WelcomePage(),
        HomePage.id: (context) => HomePage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit:** I was reading that the user must be still logged in, so what I have to do here is check if the user is not null, and then pus to the `HomePage.id`. But to check if the user is logged in I need an `async` function, and the `initialRoute` doesn't accept `Future`s.

Comment: Users stay signed in until you sign them out.  You will have to write code to check for this case as shown in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than always directly going to the `WelcomePage`, make a widget that displays a loading indicator until you determine the login state. Once this state is determined you can show either the `WelcomePage` or `HomePage` based on this state.

An example of such a widget would be the `RootPage` from this [medium article](https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-how-to-do-user-login-with-firebase-a6af760b14d5).
Example from article:

```
enum AuthStatus {
  NOT_DETERMINED,
  NOT_LOGGED_IN,
  LOGGED_IN,
}

class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  RootPage({this.auth});

  final BaseAuth auth;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _RootPageState();
}

class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  AuthStatus authStatus = AuthStatus.NOT_DETERMINED;
  String _userId = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.auth.getCurrentUser().then((user) {
      setState(() {
        if (user != null) {
          _userId = user?.uid;
        }
        authStatus =
            user?.uid == null ? AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN : AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN;
      });
    });
  }

  void loginCallback() {
    widget.auth.getCurrentUser().then((user) {
      setState(() {
        _userId = user.uid.toString();
      });
    });
    setState(() {
      authStatus = AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN;
    });
  }

  void logoutCallback() {
    setState(() {
      authStatus = AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN;
      _userId = "";
    });
  }

  Widget buildWaitingScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.NOT_DETERMINED:
        return buildWaitingScreen();
        break;
      case AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN:
        return new LoginSignupPage(
          auth: widget.auth,
          loginCallback: loginCallback,
        );
        break;
      case AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN:
        if (_userId.length > 0 && _userId != null) {
          return new HomePage(
            userId: _userId,
            auth: widget.auth,
            logoutCallback: logoutCallback,
          );
        } else
          return buildWaitingScreen();
        break;
      default:
        return buildWaitingScreen();
    }
  }
}
```